# How to not ignore files on .gitignore for Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I'm having trouble with .env files on Docker Compose.

What I'm trying to do is to add `.env` files to `.gitignore` because it has all the credentials in it and I don't want to push it to my remote repo. And I'm trying to build an app based on the `.env` file with Docker Compose.

It seems that if I don't put `*.env` in my `.gitignore` then everything seems fine.
How can I make Docker Compose to use my `.env` file as an environment variable and make it ignored for my git?

Here's my settings

Docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  backend:
    env_file:
      - .dev.env
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3000:3000

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .dev.env
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

.gitignore

```
node_modules/

logs
*.log

.DS_Store
*.env << IF REMOVED IT WORKS
```

I tried commenting my *.env on `.gitignore`

Comment: How are you deploying the compose file? Is this local or in CI?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an empty `.dockerignore` file, I think if not present it automatically takes the file `.gitignore`.